# About File Manager PHP

Tags: php

please help me
May Describe This Code ?

part One :

```
if(isset($_GET['dir'])){
    $currDir = $_GET['dir'];
}else {
    $currDir = 'files';
}
if(substr($currDir, strlen($currDir) - 1) != "/") {
    $currDir .= '/';
}
```

please this one too......................

Part Two............................

```
foreach (glob($currDir . '*') as $filename){
$fileFormat = '';
if (is_dir($filename)) {
    $type = 'folder';
} else {
    $type = 'file';
    $dotPosition = strrpos($filename, ".");
    if ($dotPosition !== false) {
        $fileFormat = substr($filename, $dotPosition + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you execute the code and see the results?

Comment: Yes . but it is not sample to underestand for me

Answer (score 0):

Part 1:
It is checking and setting the variable for directory path. If path is not provided then default is set to "files". Last line makes sure that directory's path ends with "/".

Part 2:
This section is basically checking file extension and storing it in $fileFormat variable. This code could have been better.

Comment: I can't understand part 2 please explain it more ... and why used foreach for this code ? & what's difference between file and directory and folder in programming